# nltk.word_tokenize() giving AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'defaultdict'

Tags: nltk, attributeerror, defaultdict

I am new to nltk.
I was trying some basics.

```
import nltk
nltk.word_tokenize("Tokenize me")
```

gives me this following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
nltk.word_tokenize("hi im no onee")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 101, in word_tokenize
return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 85, in sent_tokenize
tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 786, in load
resource_val = pickle.load(opened_resource)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'defaultdict'
```

Please someone help. Please tell me how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out later that I was using a backdated nltk data. The programs started to work fine as soon as I updated the data.

Answer (score 9):

I just checked it on my system.

Fix:

```
>> import nltk
>> nltk.download('all')
```

Then everything worked fine.

```
>> import nltk
>> nltk.word_tokenize("Tokenize me")
['Tokenize', 'me']
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, and then I realized that I had saved the file as tokenize.py that's why I was getting this error when I changed the name of my python file with another name it worked fine. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you need to update your nltk version. In case you are using anaconda, then do the following in terminal:

```
>> conda update nltk
```

It will update nltk. Then restart ipython and it should work!